# How does binding to collections really work?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, collectionview

Well, I'm confused.

If my control has dependency property `ItemsSource` of `IEnumerable` type and user binds collection to it what object do I have in `DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue`?

As far as I know `CollectionView` is implicitly created for collections and I expect `args.NewValue` to be of type `ICollectionView`.

From [this blog](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/387#.UNGFFuTZaX0):

> When a user binds a WPF property to a collection of data, WPF
>   automatically creates a view to wrap the collection, **and binds the
>   property to the view, not the raw collection**. This behavior always
>   happens, and is independent of CollectionViewSource.

But debugger (VS 2012, .net v.4.0) shows me that I receive original raw collection in `NewValue`. (BindsDirectlyToSource is not set and equals false by default)
How can this be?!

I cannot understand how in this case WPF controls support sorting, grouping and filtering.
How and when is CollectionView injected and used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the following extract from the Remarks section in [CollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) answers your question:

> In WPF applications, all collections have an associated default
>   collection view. Rather than working with the collection directly, the
>   binding engine always accesses the collection through the associated
>   view. To get the default view, use the
>   CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView method. An internal class based on
>   CollectionView is the default view for collections that implement only
>   IEnumerable. ListCollectionView is the default view for collections
>   that implement IList. BindingListCollectionView is the default view
>   for collections that implement IBindingListView or IBindingList.
>
> Alternatively, you can create a view of your collection in Extensible
>   Application Markup Language (XAML) by using the CollectionViewSource
>   class and then bind your control to that view. The
>   CollectionViewSource class is the XAML representation of the
>   CollectionView class. For an example, see How to: Sort and Group Data
>   Using a View in XAML.

So if you do not explicitly bind to a CollectionViewSource, a collection binding is always made to the original collection (what you get in `NewValue`), but access to the collection (e.g. get an item by index) is *always* done through the default view. Therefore the statement "binds the property to the view, not the raw collection" is not exactly true.

A quick test revealed that [GetDefaultView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview.aspx) returns a [System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.aspx) for my bound ObservableCollection.

Comment: So this means that my control HAS to request CollectionView for passed collection and there is no support of grouping, filtering and sorting out of the box. It's control's responsibility to implement aforementioned functionality, isn't it?

Comment: There is out-of-the-box support for grouping, filtering and sorting when you explicitly bind to a [CollectionViewSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.aspx). See "How to create a view" in [Binding to Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#binding_to_collections)

Comment: Only for filetring and sorting I believe. How will you own control know about created groups? Ok, lets suppose it just gets groups but items of the source collection become unavailable in this case.

Comment: See [Grouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#grouping), it says `Except for the internal class that views an IEnumerable collection, all collection views support the functionality of grouping`.

Comment: Well, List/BindingListCollectionView definitely does. The question is about my own control. When its property is bound to CollectionView it still must know how to work with groups.